# How to automatically call specific class method after it's initialization?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's imagine i have class

```
class NewSettingsAdded:  # type: NewSettingsAdded
    def __init__(self, system: str, org_id: ):

        self.system = system
        self.org_id = org_id

    def find_head_organization(self):
        "do some prepare"

    def process(self):
    " process"
```

I would like to after instance initialization automatiucally call only find_head_organization for self.
I tried to do something like

```
class OrganisationCaller(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):

        obj = type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        obj.new_init()
        return obj


class NewSettingsAdded:  # type: NewSettingsAdded
    def __init__(self, system: str, org_id: int,):

    __metaclass__ = OrganisationCaller

    self.system = system
    self.org_id = org_id

    def find_head_organization(self):
        "do some prepare"

    def process(self):
        " process"
```

But in this approach, it calls all methods after initialisation

Comment: why don't you just call `find_head_organization` at the end of `__init__` in `NewSettingsAdded`?

Comment: Yes, i can do this, i am just trying to find another way, maybe from decorator or something

Comment: But why? You can easily create a decorator for `__init__` that calls some other function, but again, *why*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is for the object to be "automatically executed upon class instantiation", just put self.run() in the init:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.bar = 1
    self.run()
```